# Regex fails with html snippet

Tags: regex

I need to extract the content of an HTML tag using RegEx. The body of text I'm searching looks like this:

```
<div class="content">
    The Price is <script type="text/javascript">document.write(123())</script>
</div>
```

I tried to use this expression, but it fails. I need to extract the "document.write(123())"

```
(?s)<div class="content">[^<]*<script type="text/javascript">(.*?)</script></div>
```

How can I modify my expression to get what I'm after?

Comment: Because you shouldn't do it like that. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1015495

Comment: The most common reason for a regex to fail is because it's a wrong tool for the job :)

Comment: You actually have requirements that **require** you to use a regex?

Comment: As I once heard:
If you had a problem and you are solving it with regular expressions, you now have two problems. :)

Comment: I have the requirement that need to do it in regex . Else i would use Jsoup happily

Comment: "I have the requirement that need to do it in regex". You mean it's like an exercise or assignment in a regex class? I ask that because, otherwise, there's no reason to really use a regex  for that.

Comment: Try an inverted character class `([^\<]+)` instead of matching all non-newline characters `(.*?)`, but pray that your JavaScript doesn't doesn't use a `<` character :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your regular expression:

- What is `(?s)`?
- You are not accounting for the space between `</script>` and `</div>`
- The forward slashes (`/`) I believe need to be escaped, i.e., `\/`

This seems to work ([**DEMO**](http://www.rubular.com/r/FA9KTcIBYk)):

```
<div class="content">[^<]*<script type="text\/javascript">(.*?)<\/script>[^<]*<\/div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot to account for spaces between `<script>` and `<div>`

`(?s)<div class="content">[^<]*<script type="text/javascript">(.*?)</script>\s*</div>`

Answer (score 1):

Extracting content from HTML using Regex is a sure road to madness. It's worse than idea of validating email addresses with Regex.

If you are using C#/.NET I can recommend [HtmlAgility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) which does awesome job at extracting content from any HTML (there is a [good answer here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack) that shows how to use it).

If you are using some other technology just look for alternative libraries that do that same thing - you are sure to find that somebody else already solved this problem.